# How to fix vue js or javascript comparison logic error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to disabled button by comparing the quantity by stock quantity. But it seems like the comparison is wrong.

I have tried to log the comparison of each value and yes it's wrong. How can 6 > 10 is true?

[image]

```
<div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <button
              class="btn btn-success"
              v-on:click="sellStockPortfolio"
              v-bind:disabled="insufficientQuantity || quantity <= 0 || !regexNumberOnly.test(quantity)"
            >Sell</button>
          </div>
```

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["regexNumberOnly"]),
    insufficientQuantity() {
      console.log("quantity: ", this.quantity);
      console.log("stock: ", this.stock.quantity);
      console.log(
        `${this.quantity} > ${this.stock.quantity} = ${this.quantity >
          this.stock.quantity}`
      );
      return this.quantity > this.stock.quantity;
    }
  },
```

I expect the button would not disabled if the quantity is less or equal to the stock quantity.

Answer (score 2):

This will be because you're comparing strings, not numbers.

If you add in `JSON.stringify` it'll be easier to spot:

```js
console.log("quantity: ", JSON.stringify(this.quantity));
console.log("stock: ", JSON.stringify(this.stock.quantity));
```

`JSON.stringify` will put quotes around the values if they're strings. Numbers will be left without quotes.

You could observe the types more directly using `typeof`:

```js
console.log(typeof this.quantity);
console.log(typeof this.stock.quantity);
```

Strings are compared character by character so `"6"` is greater than `"10"` as the character **6** in the first string is being compared to the **1** in the second string.

Try this in the console:

```js
6 > 10     // false
'6' > '10' // true
```

You don't actually need to use `JSON.stringify` to spot the type as most browsers render numbers and strings in different colors in the console. Try this:

```js
console.log("Color test", 6, "6");
```

You should find that the number `6` is in a different colour to the string `"6"`. In your picture the logged values all seem to be in the same color, suggesting they're all strings.

The leading zero on `07` also suggests it's a string. The logging wouldn't add in that leading zero if it were a number.

The best solution here is to get all your data as the right type in the first place. A quick hack is to convert the strings to numbers when performing the comparison, like this:

```js
return +this.quantity > +this.stock.quantity;
```

This is using a unary `+` to convert to a number, other ways to convert strings to numbers are available. However, I would stress again that this would be a last resort and you really need to get your data types fixed properly if at all possible.